# Loop using list index number

Tags: python, ipython

and thanks in advance!  I've got a list of words that I'm trying organize into two separate lists based on whether the index of the list item is even or odd numbered.  The list currently looks like so:

['Word 0', 'Word 1', 'Word 2', 'Word 3']

The actual list actually contains 8598 words, and I'd like to be able to create a loop to help me organize my data.  Still a relatively new Pythonista, so I'm hoping someone with a little more knowledge can help me out here so I can start messing around with this data a bit using pandas.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to iterate through your list, check wether your index is odd or not and add to a list or another one depending of this, Hope it helps

```
oddWords = []
evenWords = []
for index, value in enumerate(data):
    if index % 2 != 0:
        oddWords.append(value)
    else:
        evenWords.append(value)
```

Comment: You, my friend, must be some sort of Python wizard!  That's exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Haha no problem, but that's more about algorithmic than python itself :D,
Hope you have a good time with Python :)

Answer (score 3):

```
a = ['Word 0', 'Word 1', 'Word 2', 'Word 3']

odd = a[0::2] # start from `0` to the end, step = 2
even = a[1::2] # start from `1` to the end, step = 2
```

This may cause two-pass scan, but your dataset is pretty small, so don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try slicing leaving index 0 -

```
words = ['Word 0', 'Word 1', 'Word 2', 'Word 3']
oddIndexedWords = list1[1::2] #contains all elements from words starting from 1 iterating by 2
evenIndexedWords = list1[::2] # contains all elements from words starting from 0 iterating by 2
print oddIndexedWords
print evenIndexedWords
```

Answer (score -2):

```
data = ['0','1','2','3']
odd = []
even = []

x = 0
while x < len(data):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        even.append(data[x])
    else:
        odd.append(data[x])
    x += 1

print (odd)
print (even)
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)